# Select em windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Imaginando eu, que tenho 3 `checkbox`:

- 2.9.1
- 2.9.2
- 2.9.3

Eu queria, que eu clicar na 2.9.3, me seleciona-se todas as que estão para trás. 
É à espécie de um *select all*, mas só me selecionar de um dado número para cima que eu escolha. 
Estou a fazer estas checkbox, dentro de uma listview, e quero selecionar como disse anteriormente.

**Atualização**

```
private void Checked()
{
    foreach (UltraListViewItem listItem in listView.Items)
    {
        if (cb_selectAll.Checked == true)
        {
            listItem.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
        }
        if (cb_selectAll.Checked == false)
        {
            listItem.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compartilha o código que você já tentou fazer.

Comment: Eu fiz o código para a select all :

Comment: Acho que existe uma confusão no uso do site. Você completou a sua pergunta em uma resposta... Talvez uma lida na [FAQ do SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade?rq=1) te ajude.

Comment: Resolveu seu problema Ana ?

Comment: Ainda não fiz essa parte.

Comment: Já resolvi o meu problema. Muito OBRIGADA ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um evento para que ao marcar um item ele marque os itens anteriores;

```
 private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentValue != CheckState.Checked)
        {
            for (int i = e.Index - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ItemCheckEventArgs e) , isto não me reconhece no c#

Comment: É porque este exemplo está utilizando componentes da DevExpress, mas voce pode utilizar os componentes do windows forms : System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs

Comment: Olha o ItemCheckEventArgs não tem o e.State.

Comment: private void listView_ItemCheckStateChanged(object sender, ItemCheckStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if()
            {
                 for
            }
            
        }. Tenho isto, e agora o que coloco? Não me dá nada

Comment: Editei a resolução, no case estou utilizando uma checkedListBox;

Answer (score 1):

O método abaixo irá criar uma lista com todos os `checkbox` das versões anteriores, e por último, vamos atribuir esse método ao evento de cada `checkbox`.

```
private void SelecionaCheckVersoesAnteriores(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Esse é o checkbox que você vai clicar (dar o check)
    var checkAtivado = (CheckBox)sender;

    //Cria uma lista com todos os checkbox com um nome MENOR que o clicado
    //O texto de cada checkbox foi convertido para número para utilizarmos o operador <
    var listCheck = this.Controls?.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Text.Replace(".", ""))
                                                                 < Convert.ToInt32(checkAtivado.Text.Replace(".", "")));
    //Percorre todos os itens da lista e atribui o mesmo valor:
    //Se você dar check, então todos os anteriores vão ser checados, senão,
    //todos serão desmarcados
    foreach (var item in listCheck) {
        item.Checked = checkAtivado.Checked;
    }

    //OU Se quiser que apenas aconteça ao dar um check, ou seja, só quando ativar,
    //então marque como true diretamente
    foreach (var item in listCheck) {
        item.Checked = true;
    }
}

//Aqui estão as atribuições ao evento Check de cada checkbox
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SelecionaCheckVersoesAnteriores(sender, e);
}
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SelecionaCheckVersoesAnteriores(sender, e);
}
private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SelecionaCheckVersoesAnteriores(sender, e);
}
```